# How can I reduce noise from measurement without a Kalman Filter?

Tags: control-theory, optimal-control, linear-control, kalman-filter, system-identification

I'm going to create an adaptive Model Predictive Controller  (MPC). The model is a state space model. Due to noise, it's very difficult to determine the model order.

I'm using subspace identification method OKID/ERA and due to noise, I get many very large hankel singular values, which gives an answer how large the model will be. But noise pervent me to select the right model order.

If I had low noise, then I would have like 1 or 2 big hankel singular values, which gives the result of model order.

So in this case, I don't have a model to begin with and therefore I cannot use a kalman filter. Do you have any suggestion I could use to "remove" the noise from measurements?

Comment: A good old fashioned low-pass filter perhaps

Comment: Like a capacitor between analog in and GND?

Comment: Have you tried calculating a frequency response function (for example using Welch's method) since from that one can often also infer a good model order as well.

Comment: @KwinvanderVeen How can I do that? No, I haven't.

Comment: No, like $1/(sT+1)$

Comment: @JohanLöfberg Then it's much better to use a capacitor.

Comment: @JohanLöfberg If,you want, you can post this an an answer.

Comment: Signals and systems and filter theory was implemented using analog circuits in the past (and still). The whole idea with digital filters is that you can change your whole setup on a whim, instead of soldering up a new analog filter. Kalman filter is also just an analog circuit, if you want.

Comment: @JohanLöfberg Do you think mean average sum will solve my issue?

Comment: That's the trivial filter with low-pass character in in discrete time. Better read up on digital filters to find better alternatives

Comment: such as https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Butterworth_filter

Comment: @JohanLöfberg Thank you! I will try do find a digital filter where I can implement it in C.

Comment: All linear filters are trivial to implement in C, it's just a difference equation

Comment: Depending on your measurement setup you could also combine two measurements (if you the possibility to measure with dissimilar redundancy) by $y = \alpha y_1 + (1-\alpha) y_2$. If $y_1$ is a measurement with high static precision and $y_2$ a measurement with high dynamic precision you can choose $\alpha$ pretty high e.g. $0.90$. The low-pass filter always gives you a phase lag (depending on the order of the filter) which can negatively influence your control authority.

Answer (score 1):

Try "unscented Kalman filter" as it does not require any model.

"Ensemble Kalman filter" uses a probablistic model. Have a look at "[ensemble kalman filtering without a model](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/baa3/d79448790b2c6ae1d14d59b149af0f9e8fe6.pdf)".

Moving Horizon Estimation (MHE) in general also needs a model which would not be better than Kalman filter.

As a comment, in a very highly noisy situation, Stochastic MPC might help your optimization although it does not improve your measurement.

Comment: Thank for your answer. Can you show how a UKF works? I know the notaion of a nonlinear state space model prepresentation.